# SharePoint Filters and Custom Views Total Calculations

Tags: filter, date-time, calculated-column-formula, syntax

I have a Date column where users can enter any date they want, I also have separate column that shows the month of that same date column.

I am trying to create a filter that will count how many items in the month column equals the current month and year we are in. I would like this count to change each month.

example: The user enters 8/16/2018 in the filter it will count it but if the user enters 8/16/2017 it will not count it. Once the month changes to September the count will reset to 0 until the user enters a date in September where it will start counting all over again but with the next month.

The filter I tried to use was: Show items if the following is true [Date column] is equal to ([Today]"MMMM)

But got the error message that the filter was not supported

I'm not sure what I can do to accomplish this. Any help you can give would really go a long way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you have to create two calculated columns one to hold month start date of the given date and other to hold month end date of the given date.

Assuming given date as 16/08/2018

Create calulated column as below

StartMonthDate

```
=DATE(YEAR([DateColumn]), MONTH([DateColumn]), 1)
```

> Output will be 01/08/2018

EndMonthDate

```
=DATE(YEAR([DateColumn]), MONTH([DateColumn])+1,1)-1
```

> Output will be 31/08/2018

Now to get item count from current month you can create view with below filter

```
StartMonthDate (less than or equal to ) [Today]
AND
EndMonthDate (greather than or equal to) [Today]
```

Comment: Worked THAKS A LOT !!!!